# Bypass ACL to run update using itemsService

Tags: directus

I'm trying to run a public endpoint that update a collection item. I'm using itemsService->update() but I'm getting a **ForbiddenCollectionUpdateException** error.

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 302,
        "message": "Updating item from \"products\" collection was denied",
        "class": "Directus\\Permissions\\Exception\\ForbiddenCollectionUpdateException",
        "file": "/var/www/app/src/core/Directus/Permissions/Acl.php",
        "line": 1044
    }
}
```

I tried setting the user as admin using this snippet:

```
    $this->_acl->setPublic(false);
    $this->_acl->setUserId(1);

    $this->_acl->setCollectionPermission('products', $this->_acl::PERMISSION_FULL);
```

When I dump the value of **$this->_acl**, I can see that **globalPermissions** for product is added BUT when I tried the endpoint the exception still persist.

Any idea on how I could accomplish this?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Are you running this in an endpoint?

Try using the following syntax (setting ACL to null for me seems to bypass ACL authentication but still use the access_token for Directus activity and revisions purposes):

```
$container = \Directus\Application\Application::getInstance()->getContainer();
$dbConnection = $container->get('database');
$acl = $container->get('acl');

$tableGateway = Directus\Database\TableGatewayFactory::create('COLLECTION_NAME', [
    'connection' => $dbConnection,
    'acl' => null (false)
]);
```

Documentation: https://docs.directus.io/advanced/api/data.html#fetching-data-within-hooks-and-endpoints

Comment: I have tried the syntax you've provided before but the ACL is still being trigger when I tried it in a private window.